# Cloudfront 403 or no response error making request from S3 secured hosted website to ec2 instance maybe secured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

My website clap.com is a SPA hosted on an AWS S3 bucket. It is SSL certified. 
My ec2 server is hosted on AWS EC2. I think it's SSL certified. I ran through the process to make it SSL certified.

When I make this request `ec2-x-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3002/getProfile` to my EC2 server from my website I get this cloudfront error:

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

When I make a request with https prepended `https://ec2-x-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3002/getProfile` I never get a response back. I don't see any errors in my EC2 server.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. When I created the certificate for my EC2 server which is using **apache**, I used clap.com as the **CommonName**. I also got the CA from **ZeroSSL**.

Thoughts? This is the worst part about websites.

I've whitelisted the correct IP addresses [edit] and ports [/edit]. I have no problem SSHing into my EC2 server.

I started receiving this error when making a CURL Post request while SSHd into my EC2 Server (Probably most helpful):

```
(35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

So I thought it was a problem with my **Apache Server**. So I added `Listen 3002` in the httpd.conf file. When I restarted the server I got an error that port 3002 was being occupied. This makes sense since my node server is occupying port 3002. So...

I think I'm misunderstanding how to make my node server hosted on an EC2 SSL certified.

turning off apache I don't get the SSL23_Get_server error anymore and I get the correct response. But, when I make the post request from my website I don't get any responses.

Comment: Do the instance secuirty group allow ports 80 or 443?

Comment: edited, yes it does.

Comment: hmmm, do I have to update apache to allow for traffic to port 3002?

Comment: If you login to your instance, and `curl` from inside, does it work properly, on which port?

Comment: Failed to connect to ec2-x-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 3002: Connection refused

Comment: I mean, `curl localhost:3002` or which port it should be. Just to be sure your app works as expected on the given port.

Comment: it does work locally. I haven't changed any backend code.

Comment: So in that case, shoudn't your security group open port 3002?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I'm not worried about my local environment. I'm making a post request to my node server hosted on an EC2 where Apache is running. When I'm not using Apache I don't have a problem. So I think it has something to do with Apache.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you get blocked. You wrote "I never get a response back." Seems like a security group issue, or network acl. Something blocks the connections.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake... my node server wasn't running that's why I got that error. The error when running the node server is curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol